# Inverse observation model and Kalman filtering

Tags: kalman-filter

I hope this is the right forum to ask this question.

Sequential filtering frameworks perform 2-steps essentially:

Process model (forecast) : $x_{t+1} = f_t(x_t) + v_t$

Observation model (update): $z_t = h_t(x_t) + w_t$

Here, $v_t, w_t$ are uncorrelated zero-mean noise processes, and $f_t, h_t$ are functions (may be linear or non-linear).

For the particular case of Kalman filters, $f_t, h_t$ are *linear* and the noise processes are *Gaussian*.

In my application, the user *learns* the observation model using historical data (linear regression, for example). Since that is the case, the user might as well learn an *inverse observation model*, such that $$x_t = g_t(z_t) + \eta_t$$

Here, the underlying state vector is expressed as a function of observations $z_t$. Assume that $\eta_t$ is Gaussian.

With the inverse observation model, the update step is simplified. Apply $g_t$ to $z_t$ and then simply *assimilate* the resulting vector (call it $\hat{x}_t$) to $x_t$. The assimilation here is a weighted addition of two Gaussian distributed variables where the weights are in inverse proportion of their covariance matrices (for Kalman optimal solution).

So my question is: is there anything wrong with this approach of using an inverse observation model instead of an observation model? The advantage is that I can define the weighted addition as an operator in my data structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand well, what you propose is correct IF what is learned at time $t$ is uncorrelated from what you already know. The (conventional) Kalman update equation is a linear combination of the old state vector and the innovation,
which is orthogonal to the old state vector.

Comment: What I am suggesting is, if $h_t$ is an invertible function, the observation model can be re-written as ${h_t}^{-1}(z_t) = x_t + w'_t$. Now Kalman update step is just a weighted linear sum of $x_t$ and ${h_t}^{-1}(z_t)$ (let's call this $\hat{x}_t$). I don't see why things have to be _uncorrelated_ as you pointed out. Could you please explain that a bit?

Comment: This adds the condition of invertibility of $h_t$ (which was no apparent in the original question). Anyway, the problem is with your statement that $z_t$ is historical data. In your original formulation, this would imply that information that is incorporated into the state vector at moment $t-1$ via $g(z_{t-1})$ would be reused in $t$ via g(z_{t})$.

Comment: Additionally, $h^{-1}(z_t) \not= x(t) + w_t'$ (unless $h^{-1}()$ is linear or you make $w_t'$ depend on $x_t$).